# Question hijacking after posting a bounty

Tags: discussion, questions, editing, bounty

I recently came across [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/24321/25318), which seemed like it arose from a relatively simple misunderstanding of how Ethereum works.  The sole answer seemed to assume a greater degree of understanding Ethereum than appropriate to the question.  Another user had placed a bounty on it claiming it hadn't received enough attention.

I provided an answer which I thought addressed the [original question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/revisions/24321/1) as asked.

The user who posted the bounty (nominally different from the OP) then [changed the question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/24321/revisions) to be about setting instead of getting information in a specific wallet UI, and not the same wallet UI as the OP had asked about.

While I recognize we have the Investor and Altruist badge to encourage bounties on others' questions, does offering a bounty give more license to significantly change the essence of a question, especially while the bounty is live?

From an answerer's perspective I would think that substantial edits to questions during bounty periods would be discouraged, but from the bounty-poster's perspective it might make sense to be more permissive in helping that poster get the answers they're actually looking for, whether or not the question originally asked does a good job of eliciting those answers.

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me that this was a good-faith attempt to clarify the question according to what the original poster meant to ask. Personally, I agree with the editor that this question is asking how to set `msg.sender` in a local call, not a transaction. The addition of "MyCrypto" does substantially broaden the scope and should not have been included.

Without the input of the original poster it is hard to know for sure, but I don't think in this case that the meaning of the question was substantially changed.

In general, however, adding a bounty does not give the bounty issuer arbitrary control over the question, and in fact even the original poster of the question may not vandalize their post by substantially changing the meaning.

Please continue to report edits that seem to change the meaning of a question, and we can review it on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: "How to check" and "how to set" (the core edit) seem like very different things, or at least they have different answers. In another part of the question, consistent with the title edit, "any way to know who the caller is" is different than "indicate who the caller should be."  Answers to the new question also change more from one wallet UI to another.